# How to get files list from local network and copy files using Delphi + Android?

Tags: android, delphi, copy, smb

Phone via Wi-Fi and Windows PC using same network.

At PC I have shared folder `\\192.168.1.36\Exchange` (without any password).

I need to get a list of files from this folder and copy them to the Phone via Delphi 10.1 + Android 8.0.

I try to use this example:

https://github.com/LongDirtyAnimAlf/Delphi-Android-SMB

but it always raises an `SMBAuthException` error.

Comment: The source you reference is clearly marked "Proof of concept!!" That should tell you two things: 1) that code isn't guaranteed to work, and 2) what you're trying to accomplish is not an appropriate approach. The likely appropriate solution to your problem is to not use Windows file sharing in the first place, but something more standard, such as HTTP. Whatever file(s) you're trying to access can instead be hosted on a web server. Only time you should consider using Windows file sharing from Android is if the nature of the app is based around the idea to begin with.

Comment: It is not necessary to use this library but main task is copy file from Windows shared folder to phone without special program at Win PC.

Comment: You'll either need to figure out how to fix that code you found, or write your own implementation. I hope the app you're writing has a good reason for this. It's not about whether or not there's a special program on the PC side. It's about how your users will actually need to use it.  Is the purpose of the app rooted around the requirement of accessing Windows shares? If not, then you need a different solution.

Comment: Have you tried accessing this network folder from another computer? I recently learned the hard way that on Windows 7 sharing a folder from a user account which doesn't have password set will prevent you from accessing to that folder from another computer. But as soon as I set a password for that account and then provided the needed password on credential popup window which appear when you first try to connect to shared folder everything worked as it should.

Comment: Of course I can access this folder from all computers at this network without any problems. P.S. It's just turn off password protectiom.